# How to unit test/mock requests.get(url) & its response

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, mocking

I am having trouble unit testing a function that uses Kenneth Reitz's [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v2.0-0/index.html) library:

The following function is to be unit tested:

```
def getPage(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    r.raise_for_status()    # raises HTTPError if necessary
    dom = fromstring(r.text)
    dom.make_links_absolute(url)
    return dom
```

My unit test is at the moment as follows. (Though clearly this does not work.)

```
@patch('requests.Response')
@patch('requests.Response.raise_for_status', return_value=None)
@patch('requests.get', return_value=requests.Response)
def test_getPage(mock_requests_get, mock_RFS, mock_response):
    with open("domtest.htm", "r") as testfile:
        mock_response.text = testfile.read()    

    dom = getPage('http://www.test.com')
    eq_(dom, dom_test)
```

The resulting traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nose\case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mock.py", line 1201, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "C:\...\test_myfile.py", line 79, in test_getPage
    dom = getPage('http://www.test.com')
  File "C:\...\myfile.py", line 67, in getPage
    r.raise_for_status()    # raises HTTPError if necessary
TypeError: unbound method raise_for_status() must be called with Response instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

How does one unit test a function like this using mocking rather than a temporary webserver? I tried pickling the response and setting it instead as return value for requests.get() but it cannot be pickled.

Answer (score 5):

Very late, but I really like the HTTPretty library for this exact problem:

http://falcao.it/HTTPretty/

Comment: The docs are missing information about how to inspect the request your code has made. And from what I've gathered so far, you only have access to the last made request, which is insufficient when testing a function/method that makes more than one request. Otherwise, this is a pretty good project. -- Also, I've used https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wsgi_intercept in the past, but this is a bit overkill for simple calls to external services.